# Mysql set to default?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in mysql I can set to default?

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET thisColumn = thisColumn(DEFAULT) WHERE id = ?");
```

Is there a function to set to default in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [`DEFAULT` keyword:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> Use the keyword DEFAULT to set a column explicitly to its default value. This makes it easier to write INSERT statements that assign values to all but a few columns, because it enables you to avoid writing an incomplete VALUES list that does not include a value for each column in the table. Otherwise, you would have to write out the list of column names corresponding to each value in the VALUES list.
>
> You can also use DEFAULT(col_name) as a more general form that can be used in expressions to produce a given column's default value.

`DEFAULT(col_name)` can only be used if a default is explicitly set for that column, but  `DEFAULT` should always work.

Untested, but this should work:

```
   UPDATE accounts SET thisColumn = DEFAULT WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Ye this worked brilliantly thanks :) I actually could't find it in the docs myself thanks again :)